Format the firebase ServerValues.TIMESTAMP into Date Format in android
I want to convert the ServerValues.TIMESTAMP into "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS" format.
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    if ( date!= null && !date.isEmpty()) {
        result.put(AppConstantClass.EVENT_DATE, date);
    }
    if (time != null && !time.isEmpty()) {
        result.put(AppConstantClass.EVENT_TIME, time);
    }
    if (userId != null && !userId.isEmpty()) {
        result.put(AppConstantClass.EVENT_USED_ID, userId);
    }

    result.put("timestamp",  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    return result;
}

I want to convert the ServerValues.TIMESTAMP into "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS" Format and store it into Firebase Realtime Database.
how can i format the "result.put("timestamp",  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);" into "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS" .
Thanks in advance

You can’t literally. According to the documentation Firebase replaces ServaerValue.TIMESTAMP with time since the Unix epoch in milliseconds, not with dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss. Sure you can store the current time stamp in that format, it’s not really recommended, and if you insist, you will need other means.
